Can you convert Line to Polygon by Drawing in GRASS GIS
How can I make a line feature into a polygon in GRASS GIS by drawing a closed shape? I'm looking for a method to manually edit a vector layer and create a polygon by simply drawing its outline and closing the loop. Is there a specific tool or workflow for this?

You almost certainly want to ask this over on the [gis.se] site instead.
